# How to include Grand Total box in Report viewer for the report displayed?

Tags: sql, reportviewer

I'm generating a report in C# using "MicrosoftReportViewer".
Report contains 3 columns Sno,Components,TotalCost.
Each column having 'n' number of values, among which I need to sum the TotalCost Column and the grandtotal should be displayed at the end of the Report.

I'm able to produce report completely.
I don't know how to display grandtotal at the end of the report.

suppose TotalCost column having values 500,200,100.....100 then,
GRANDTOTAL =(500+200+100+..+100)  ---> this is needed to be displayed in the report

How to attach a GrandTotal Box at the end of the Report?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the report, insert a textbook at the bottom. Right click on the textbook and click on "Expression". In the dialog box, write `=Sum("blah blah blah")` . The text inside sum could be List of data from your dataset or other fields in the dataset or just constant values. Hope this helps